# F# I cannot make a countdown from 10 to 0

Tags: timer, f#

I'm quite new to F# and wanted to attempt to make a simple countdown; however, in the code below, it tells me there is something wrong with the "t..0".

```
let countdown x =
let mutable t = 10
for t..0 do 
        t=t-1
```

I want it to countdown in the terminal from 10 to 0.

Comment: 'tells me there is something wrong with the "t..0"'. Very specifically, what, *exactly*, does the error message say?

Comment: It says "Unexpected symbol" ".." in pattern"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three issues with your snippet. First, you do not need to decrement the `t` in a `for` loop - this happens automatically. Second, if you want a range like `t .. 0` to go down, you need to specify `-1` as the step. Also, your syntax for a `for` loop needs to define a variable (and you do not need to do this outside of the loop):

```
let countdown x =
  for t in 10 .. -1 .. 0 do 
    printfn "Counting: %d" t
```

Comment: I realize this is a long time ago but thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Tomas' answer shows the range syntax, but there's also the imperative syntax, analogous to `for` loops.

```
for i = 10 downto 1 do 
  printfn "Counting: %d" i
```

For counting up, use `for i = 0 to 10`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
var i = 10;
var interval = setInterval( increment, 1000);
  
function increment(){
  i = i - 1;
  if(i <= -1) {
    return
  }
  console.log(i);
}
```

**Breakdown:**

Where the countdown should start:

```
var i = 10;
```

The increment interval: (usually 1000ms)

```
var interval = setInterval( increment, 1000);
```

The actual countdown:

```
function increment(){
i = i - 1;
```

If counter goes into negative numbers, stop counting:

```
if(i <= -1) {
return
}
```

Write result in the console log:

```
  }
  console.log(i);
}
```